# Giving Wine applications more privileges (like listening on ports below 1024)

Tags: wine

I've had a problem with [making QuickVPN work with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17873/problems-with-cisco-quickvpn-client/18336). I've got a feeling that it's because the Windows only application needs to listen on port 500, which it cannot without privileges. As you should never run Wine as root, how do you at least give it some privileges?

All I've found is that you should use "[Posix Capabilities](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-96bebfa287b4288974de0df23351f278b0d41014)", but I haven't been able to figure out how exactly I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to grant the "bind to privileged ports" capability to Wine with:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/wine
```

Please let us know if it worked.

Comment: And run `sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin` to install `setcap` if you don't already have it

Comment: The capability seems to have been set, but the VPN program is still not working. I don't think it will ever work with wine. Thanks though.

Comment: You may need to give caps to both /usr/bin/wine and /usr/bin/wineserver, as well as the actual executable you're launching